# is there a way to see the replaced selection after search and replace in vim

Tags: vim

When replacing a regex in vim using search and replace in vim, is there a way to see the result before moving onto the next replace.

The interactive option shows the string matching the regex before replace, but with a complex regex it might or might not work as expected so.

If theres a plugin or hack or default option to achieve this i would really like to know.

Answer (score 1):

The [traces.vim](https://github.com/markonm/traces.vim) plugin provides range, pattern and substitute preview for Vim.

Neovim has a native method to do substitutions previews. I believe it is the `'inccommand'` option.

Comment: I installed traces the it was given in the repo and through pathogen. it didn't effect anything. is there some vimrc config that i have to do for this.